# How to save (or keep) added controls in run time [asp.net / c#]

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

First sorry for the inaccurate first question. Now i edited it.

My question/problem is how to **save (and keep)** controls added at run time in my code? (so if i add label and text box at run time in program it must be in my code like if i implemented it manual)

For example text box added dynamically, but it disappears after reboot the program:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "textBox1";
        txt.Text = "helloo";
        form1.Controls.Add(txt);

        var lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "label1";
        lbl.Text = "I am a label";
        form1.Controls.Add(lbl);

        // Increase the number added and add the new label and textbox
        TotalNumberAdded++;
        AddControls(TotalNumberAdded);
    }
```

I planned to implement asp.net web application where can users add additional tasks next to pre-implemented.

Thanks for answers,
Rookie programmer Alex :)

Comment: Side note: please check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove to see policy on signatures/thank you notes in the posts.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my question is not duplicate any more and sorry for inaccurate question. Should now my question lose duplicate status, that someone can answer me?

Comment: Please clarify why https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx was not enough for you and what additional help you are looking from SO. Also I'm not sure why after reading discussions on Meta about text unrelated to the question you've edited even more of such text into the post...

Answer (score 0):

For adding controls at runtime you can try the PlaceHolder control like this:

```
    Button b = new Button();
    b.ID = "YourID";
    b.Text = "Button";

    PlaceHolderTest.Controls.Add(b);
```

but I dont know any method to add this to your assembly. Maybe you should consider redesigning to use multiple User Controls, which gives you the ability to load different User Controls that contains your controls, meaning you have to create multiple User Controls.